# Akka actorSelection(String) does not work on TCP

Tags: java, akka

I'm trying to experiment with Akka and to use actors on different PCs. To start, I'm trying to connect to actors in the same JVM and in the same `ActorSystem`, but using a remote selection. However, I'm failing even at this simple task. The following is the minimized code that shows my problem. I believe I'm programmatically adding all the needed configuration. When I run the code as it is, using the line marked with `/*works*/`, I get `B received dd`; if I swap `/*works*/` with `/*fails*/`, I get `[INFO]..[akka://N1/deadLetters]..was not delivered`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I access `B` using the remote selector?

```
class A extends AbstractActor {
  public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
      .match(String.class, s -> {
        ActorSelection selection = context().actorSelection(
          /*fails*/ //"akka.tcp://N1@127.0.0.1:2500/user/B"
          /*works*/ "akka://N1/user/B"
        );

        selection.tell("dd", self());
      })
      .build();
   }
}

class B extends AbstractActor {
  public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
      .match(String.class, s -> {
        System.out.println("B received " + s);
      })
      .build();
  }
}

public class AkkaS1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Config config =
      ConfigFactory
        .parseString("akka.remote.netty.tcp.port = 2500")
        .withFallback(
          ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.remote.netty.hostname = 127.0.0.1"))
        .withFallback(ConfigFactory.load());

    ActorSystem s = ActorSystem.create("N1", config);
    ActorRef a = s.actorOf(Props.create(A.class, () -> new A()), "A");

    s.actorOf(Props.create(B.class, () -> new B()), "B");
    a.tell("Please discover b", ActorRef.noSender());

    System.out.println(">>> Press ENTER to exit <<<");
    try {
      System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    } finally {
      s.terminate();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe I'm programmatically adding all the needed configuration.

You appear to be missing a couple of settings: `akka.actor.provider = remote` and `akka.remote.enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]`. Also, change `akka.remote.netty.hostname` to `akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname`.

According to the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/remoting.html#configuration), the minimum configuration is the following:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = remote
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2500
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm having a lot of problem to "collect" the right documentation navigating their guides and tutorials